# How to train data using svmtrain in Matlab? (memory error)

Tags: matlab, memory, svm

I'm new to Matlab. I want to train a data using svm in Matlab 7.6
Here's my code:

```
clc;
close all;
clear;

training = csvread('training.csv');
trainingClass = csvread('trainingClass.csv');
trainingClass = logical(trainingClass);

svmStruct = svmtrain(training,trainingClass);
```

The size of training matrix is 7396x3. I use 0 and 1 as the values of trainingClass and then convert it to logical because the data type is double when I load it. But, I get error in svmtrain function.

> ??? Error using ==> qr Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your
>   options.
>
> Error in ==> qpsub>eqnsolv at 1007 [Q,R]=qr(ACTSET');
>
> Error in ==> qpsub at 195
>       [Q,R,A,B,X,Z,how,ACTSET,ACTIND,ACTCNT,aix,eqix,neqcstr,ncstr,
>       ...
>
> Error in ==> quadprog at 302
>   [X,lambdaqp,exitflag,output,dum1,dum2,msg]= ...
>
> Error in ==> svmtrain at 463
>           [alpha, fval, exitflag, ...
>
> Error in ==> classifier at 9 svmStruct =
>   svmtrain(training,trainingClass);

Which parameters must be set when I call svmtrain function? I've tried the one in Matlab Help with fisheriris data and there's no problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the "Memory Usage and Out of Memory Error" section under `help svmtrain`? It describes the parameters you could adjust here.

Comment: Can you post the data you're training with? I've used `svmtrain` before with that datasize without an issue. An alternative is to use libsvm for better performance and accuracy.